Wordpress SMTP plugins causing issues with admin-ajax.php
I have a Wordpress website recently migrated to new dedicated hosting. I can't make any SMTP plugin work: no matter which one I try, my admin-ajax.php keeps loading and loading... this is causing also my website to stop working (all the forms just won't submit). I have contacted my hosting company and they can't see any issue in there. Upon checking, I found this error: "AH01630: client denied by server configuration: [MYPATH]/index.php, referer: http://[MYWEBSITE]". Strangely, the "referee" is a HTTP URL, but my website is in HTTPS. I believe it's a CORS error, but I can't really make it work.
I have tried WP Mail SMTP, FluentSMTP and others and still no luck. A plugin I have tried once didn't cause the error in question, but was returning a "can't connect to the host" generic message.
Any help you can give me, will be much appreciated.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
